# Use icon to run Android Studio - Linux Mint

Tags: linux, android-studio, linux-mint

When I want to run Android Studio I must go to terminal from `androidstudio/bin` then type `./studio.sh`.

How can I use icon to run Android Studio in my desktop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Android Development.

> Tip: To make Android Studio available in your list of applications,
>   select **Tools > Create Desktop Entry** from the Android Studio menu bar.

For more info refer [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install).

Comment: I'm not followed the installation instruction from official website, so I don't notice that tip. Thank You very much!

Comment: You are very much welcome.